# what does this Spring JSON endpoint break in Jboss/Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, jboss

what does this Spring JSON endpoint break in Jboss/Tomcat ? I tried to add this to an existing APPLICATION and It worked until I started refactoring the code and now the errors do not point to anything that is logical to me.

Here is my code a controller and Helper class to keep things clean. 
Controller.Java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class PropertiesDisplayController {

@Nonnull
private final PropertiesDisplayHelper propertiesHelper;

/**
 * @param propertiesHelper
 */
@Nonnull
@Autowired
public PropertiesDisplayController(@Nonnull final PropertiesDisplayHelper propertiesHelper) {
    super();
    this.propertiesHelper = propertiesHelper;
}


@Nonnull
@RequestMapping("/localproperties")
public @ResponseBody Properties localProperties() throws ConfigurationException, IOException {
    return propertiesHelper.getLocalProperties();
}

@Nonnull
@RequestMapping("/properties")
public @ResponseBody Properties applicationProperties() throws IOException,
        ConfigurationException {
    return propertiesHelper.getApplicationProperties();

}

}
```

this would be the Helper.java

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

import org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class PropertiesDisplayHelper {

/** Static location of properties in for SSO */
private static String LOCAL_PROPERTIES_LOCATION =
    "local.properties";

/** Static strings for masking the passwords and blank values */
private static String NOVALUE = "**NO VALUE**";
/** Static strings for masking the passwords and blank values */
private static String MASKED = "**MASKED**";


@Nonnull
public Properties getApplicationProperties() throws ConfigurationException {

    final Properties properties = new Properties();
    final Configuration configuration = AppConfiguration.Factory.getConfiguration();

    // create a map of properties
    final Iterator<?> propertyKeys = configuration.getKeys();
    final Map<String, String> sortedProperties = new TreeMap<String, String>();

    // loops the configurations and builds the properties
    while (propertyKeys.hasNext()) {
        final String key = propertyKeys.next().toString();
        final String value = configuration.getProperty(key).toString();
        sortedProperties.put(key, value);
    }
    properties.putAll(sortedProperties);
    // output of the result
    formatsPropertiesData(properties);
    return properties;
}


@Nonnull
public Properties getLocalProperties() throws ConfigurationException, IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    final Properties properties = new Properties();
    // imports file local.properties from specified location
    // desinated when the update to openAM12
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(LOCAL_PROPERTIES_LOCATION);
        properties.load(fis);
    } finally {
        // closes file input stream
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(fis);
    }
    formatsPropertiesData(properties);
    return properties;
}

void formatsPropertiesData(@Nonnull final Properties properties) {
    for (final String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
        String value = properties.getProperty(key);

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
            value = NOVALUE;
        } else if (key.endsWith("ssword")) {
            value = MASKED;
        } else {
            value = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(value);
        }
        // places data to k,v paired properties object
        properties.put(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

they set up a json display of the properties in application and from a file for logging. Yet now this no intrusive code seems to break my entire application build.

Here is the error from Jboss

20:33:41,559 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "openam.war" was rolled back with the following failure message:
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"APPLICATION.war\".STRUCTURE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"APPLICATION.war\".STRUCTURE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"APPLICATION.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018740: Failed to mount deployment content
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:APPLICATION.war (Access is denied)"}}

and the Errors from Tomcat

http://pastebin.com/PXdcpqvc

I am at a lost here and think there is something I just do not see.

Comment: Seems to be more of a configuration issue rather then a coding issue. Can you post some of your relevant config files?

Comment: Spring Config like XML files or Server Config like Jboss/Tomcat ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution was at hand. The missing component was @Component annotation on the helper class.